# validate antiforgerytoken failed via jQuery Ajax in ASP.NET Core in subdomain app

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, subdomain, antiforgerytoken

I am working on a project that needs to send post via jQuery Ajax in ASP.NET Core.

```
$.ajax({
            url: _url,
            headers: {
                [tokenheadername]: token
            },
            type: 'POST',
            data: _data,
            success: function (r) { location.reload(); },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                swal('Error', 'Cannot update entry!' + XMLHttpRequest.status, 'error');
            },

        });
```

The controller action has a [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute,

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager,User")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEntry(Guid id,string filepath,string originalfilename, bool isvideo)
    {
       ...
        return Ok();
    }
```

Below is the Antiforgery setting in startup file:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "__RequestVerificationToken"; 
            options.Cookie.Name = Configuration["domain"];
        });
```

It works very well on my local development debug environment. However it fails on product. The product app is in a **submain**.  The Error code is 400.

Really appreciate it for any help.

Comment: Don't you have a dev or test enviroment that it analog to production? You should not consider that your localhost is analog to production. In any case the error is clear: 400 Bad Request. Consider use some kind of log in order to register the petition.

Comment: When you run the project in a production environment, what are the specific errors reported in the log?